# Designing of a voltage to current converter schematic

Tags: converter, power-supply

Voltage is from a sensor (0 to 4 V), and load is within -100 nA and +100nA, where 0V should be converted to -100nA and 4V to +100nA.

Here is my last trial (picture below.)

I got the -100nA for 0V and +100nA for 4V as I wanted, but the curve is not a straight line (I assume it's supposed to be totally linear) since I use non-symmetrical power supply for the op amp (for the minus terminal I use 8V battery and 4V as a battery for + terminal of the op amp).

Do you have some hints or links for a good textbook?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload a higher quality/resolution picture? The current picture is small and when zoomed in unreadable.

Comment: Please state what electrical characteristics your load has and how it is connected to the rest of the proposed system. Also show your power supplies. Your current diagrams are just blurs - did you not check what you posted?

Comment: Sorry my picture is really blurs.  Try new one please

Comment: I won't ask again: *Please state what electrical characteristics your load has*

Comment: I don't know electrical characteristics of the load, is so important while designing such converter? I've been asked to get converter from this voltage to this current

Comment: @MedetkhanAltynbek then you've been given insufficient design requirement: yes, that information is extremely crucial. This all reads like you don't really *understand* what you're designing for which purpose.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you for the information. Perhaps you may suggest some good article or a textbook that going to be useful like what are the crucial requirements, what should I change to get bipolar output or which resistors affect on the curve's behavior

Comment: @MedetkhanAltynbek honestly, I don't know what to recommend – this all feels like you are designing something very technically challenging that you need practical real-world experience, at the same time, you don't seem to have an undergrad-level understanding of opamp circuits, so I'd go with: start with the basics of opamp circuits, and work your way up to extremely low-bias current and offset voltage circuitry, which will quickly leave the scope of classical textbooks

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks, I'll try to follow your recommendations

Answer (score 3):

80 MΩ is not a realistic resistor value. That's in the range of resistance of creepage on the surface of circuit boards. 
1 GΩ? You got to be kidding! Have you ever seen a 1 GΩ resistor on a board¹?

5 pF is also a relatively rare capacitor resistor value. That's the equivalent capacitance of a few millimeter of trace over a ground plane; far too low.

Go back, design something that doesn't require any resistors of critical value of > 4.7 MΩ. You probably want something where the largest resistors are in the 100 kΩ region, so you don't have to worry too much about bias currents into the opamp.

Now, let's talk about what you want to *do*: 200 nA output range! You'll need to operate this very very far away from any electrical device, as that is very low current, and you will most likely picking that or more up from EMI.

So, I think you need to go back a step in your design process, and try to understand the measurement problem you're solving a bit better and come up with a different approach alltogether – or you're not telling us very important things (like this happening in liquid nitrogen in an RF isolated room...).

---

Take a 3mm × 3mm × 3mm cube of especially dry air, attach electrodes to two opposites sides: that's a 1 GΩ resistor. I will gladly ship you a box of 37000 raw 1 GΩ air-cores for the cheap price of 100€; you just have to cut the air into shape.

Comment: 1 G\$\Omega\$ is readily available, quick look at Farnell gives plenty. Starting at 50p a piece, £1 more common.

Comment: @awjlogan yes, but you have to realize you can't *use* that resistor in plain air unless you take precautions to avoid the air and surface creepage paths – hence my short calculation on the resistance of a 3³ mm³ cube of air.

Comment: Of course - I interpreted "Have you ever seen a 1 G\$\Omega\$ resistor?" to mean "these do not exist" :)

Comment: @awjlogan :) fair point!